# Source code is not visible in dev container

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, containers, vscode-devcontainer

I have tried to open a .NET project to be opened in dev container in VS code.  I have added dev container configuration files for .NET core with SQL Server using add container configuration menu.  Then I have tried to open the code in container using Reopen in Container Menu.

The .NET Core and SQL Server container is getting built but the source code is not visible in container but it is visible in opening locally.  I don't get what is happening.

Can anyone please get me out of it?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled bitlocker for my drive where the source code resides but unlocked while wokring on dev container.  I am able to view the source code after disabled the bitlocker for the drive.  But I am not sure how unlocked bitlocker caused issue and I am forced to disable bitlocker to get it worked and view the source code in explorer.